# How to get the data from one view controller class into another one to display in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13, ios12

I am a beginner at Swift. I have two viewControllers: 1 of them has a button which I =linked to another view Controller which contains a tableView. I want to get the array of URL strings from the first view controller to display in a TableView in the second view controller and update while the user is browsing using WebKit View. How can I do this in Swift.

Comment: What do you mean by updating the second view controller while the user is browsing using WebKitView? Does that button display the secondViewController?

Comment: Please add a [example] describing what you have already tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)